# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded error in Python class

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to get the children list in text format from my Node class. I need this to be able to print the structure in JSON format.

When I am trying to call the `getchildren()` method or directly use the same code in `__str__`, in both cases I get a max recursion error. It comes with 'Above line was executed 196 times'.

I got some solutions saying increase this limit, that may solve my problem and I will try that if nothing else works, but am not able to get why am I getting this error.

It is something like I am trying to create a JSON of something that was supposed to be an XML so its quite nested and the source is a CSV file, the code shows a single Node of data.

Am pretty new to Python and stuff like this works well in Java so confused.

I have this code:

```
class Node:
    _attributeDictionary = {}
    _lst = []

    def __init__(self, tag):
        self._tag = tag

    def setAttribute(self, attributeName, attributeValue):
        self._attributeDictionary [attributeName]= attributeValue

    def setChild(self, node):
        self._lst.append(node)

    def getchildren(self):
        s = "["
        for l in self._lst:
            s = s + str(l) + "],"
        return s[:-1]

    def __str__(self):
        s = "["
        for l in self._lst:
            s = s + str(l) + "],"
        return "'" + self._tag + "':" + str(self._attributeDictionary) + "," + s[:-1] + ""


nodeA=Node("A")
nodeA.setAttribute("attA","valA")
nodeB=Node("B")
nodeB.setAttribute("attA","valB")
nodeA.setChild(nodeB)
print(str(nodeA))
```

Error:

```
s = s + str(l) + "],"
[Previous line repeated 196 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: If you want to print in JSON format, why are you putting single quotes around the tag instead of double quotes?

Comment: Also, in JSON an object should be surrounded by `{}` not `[]`.

Comment: Shouldn't `setAttribute()` add a new attribute to the dictionary, not replace the entire dictionary with just one attribute?

Comment: E.g. `self._attributeDictionary[attributeName] = attributeValue`

Comment: Thanks for pointing all this out. Noted. This is dummy code a lot needs to be refined but need to solve the recursion error .Is there a solution recursion error?

Comment: The problem is that all your nodes are using the same `_list` variable. So every node is a child of itself.

Comment: That's why it was linked to that duplicate.

Comment: Thanks go the answer. The variables lst and dictionary should be declared inside __init__()